# Папка сайта В Windows Server 2008.

Tags: веб-программирование, windows-server

Здравствуйте!
Где в windows server 2008 находится папка с сайтом, где располагается сам сайт, на который можно попасть непосредственно из интернета? Спасибо.

---

Выискал в корне системы папку **inetpub / wwwroot** , в которой явно располагается некий пример  на IIS, но хотелось бы узнать, где папка с сайтом...

Comment: apach? iis?

Comment: Да! IIS . .

Comment: с какими сайтами? в папке ввв - создавай свои и там они будут

Comment: Зашел в корень системы, диск "C:\", там есть вот такая папка:
>    inetpub / wwwroot

Не обессудьте, опыт работы с Windows - серверами --- 0

Comment: сайт на сервере уже какой-то есть?

Comment: Да, конечно! Вот сервер - http://vm2336.hvm.agava.net

Comment: по адресу localhost можешь перейти на страничку-приветствия IIS? в папке wwwroot, есть эта страничка?

Comment: Да, в папке есть HTML-страничка и еще парочка файлов...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: так вот]

Comment: Вот я зашел в SERVER MANAGER, затем в конфигурации->Services, а куда потом? Спасибо...

Comment: Где расположена утилита Internet Information Services ?

Comment: ПУСК - и в строке поиска вводишь  Internet Information Services

Comment: Вся проблема оказалась в конфигурационном файле дефолтного сайта - web.config =) Но я вам все равно благодарен)))